# How to detect net core 3.1 windows desktop app runtime is installed through NSIS script

Tags: .net, .net-core, nsis

I have a .net windows application installation setup created using NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System). All the relevant .net framework and other dependencies are checked and installed through the NSIS script. This setup was initially built for .net framework 4.8 application. But now I want to upgrade it to install a .net core 3.1 application. Can someone please help me on how we can detect the target machine has .net core 3.1 windows desktop runtime is installed through the NSIS script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting .NET is always a joy. Detecting it in NSIS should be fairly simple once you know the general method but even finding that information is hard.

I don't have .NET Core installed so I cannot verify any of this but from what I gather you should look for [the global install location](https://github.com/dotnet/designs/blob/main/accepted/2020/install-locations.md) in the registry:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
SetRegView 32 ; Always use the 32-bit view
ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86" "InstallLocation" ; x86, x64, arm or arm64 and only for Core v3 and later
SetRegView lastused
${If} $1 == ""
    StrCpy $1 "$ProgramFiles32\dotnet" ; might want to change this if not x86?
${EndIf}
```

Once you know the location (or hope the default location exists) you are supposed to execute dotnet.exe with a command line switch. Depending on who you ask, this might be `--info`, `--version` or `--list-runtimes`.

```
nsExec::ExecToStack '"$1\dotnet.exe" --info'
Pop $0 ; Return
Pop $2 ; Output
${If} $0 != "error"
    MessageBox mb_ok "TODO: Parse $2"
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Anders thanks for the tip this works really well. But has a very small issue. In my machine, there are a lot of runtimes installed and the string variable $2 can't hold all the data it returns when executing dotnet --list-runtimes and after 1023 it got trimmed. I saw the string max limit of NSIS is 1024 any help with this?

Comment: Write to a file and process it line by line, something like `nsExec::Exec '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /C "$1\dotnet.exe"  --list-runtime > "$pluginsdir\list.txt"'` and then parse that file with FileOpen, FileRead

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered already, but just in case, this is how I solved it without checking windows registry.

```
 # Check if .NET core 3.1.14 is installed
   nsExec::ExecToStack /OEM 'cmd /c dir "%windir%\system32" | dotnet --list-runtimes | find /c /i "Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.14"'
   Pop $0
   Pop $1
   StrCpy $2 $1 1
   StrCmp $2 "1" 0 version_not_found
      goto version_found
   version_not_found:
      MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "\
            Application cannot be installed!$\r$\n$\r$\n\
            Microsoft .NET Core 3.1.14 not installed yet.$\r$\n$\r$\n\
            Open the page to download and install it?" IDNO +2 
      ExecShell open "https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/3.1"
      Quit
   version_found:
```